# Numerical integrals and derivatives over implicit variables

Tags: python, math, numpy, numerical

I have an array representing an independent variable `r = {r_0, r_1, ..., r_N}`, and three arrays representing functions of that variable: `n(r) = {n_0, ..., n_N}`, `p(r) = ...`, and `E(r) = ...`.

I'd like to calculate a new function, `f(E)`,

[image]
but I'm confused because the independent variable `r` isn't used.

I was thinking that I could calculate `dn/dp` as `(dn/dr)/(dp/dr)`, but I'm not sure what to do about the lingering `dp`.  And should I define a new grid (e.g. evenly spaced) of `E` which I integrate over?

---

***Edit***:  My current plan is to treat this as,

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me like your integrand has a `dp/dp` term, so you can represent f(E) as `\frac{d}{dE}\int_0^E\frac{1}{\sqrt{E-p}} dn`. Then `n` is a function of `r`, so `dn` is a function of `r` and `dr`.

Comment: Good point @murgatroid99, but somehow `p` needs to get integrated over... Not sure how that works

Comment: By the 2nd Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the right-hand side simplifies to `\frac{dn}{dp} \frac{1}{\sqrt{E-p}}` evaluated at `p = E` (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html). Unless `\frac{dn}{dp} = 0` at `p = E`, I guess you have problems.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski If `p = E`, then `\frac{1}{\sqrt{E-p}} = 1/0` and you can't evaluate it anyway.

Comment: I would suggest asking about the integration itself at math.stackexchange.com. They can give you more help than we can in the comments, and they have LaTeX support.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That is exactly the point. The expression definitely diverges *unless* `\frac{dn}{dp} = 0` at `p = E`. Even in that case, it still may diverge.

Comment: It's also possible that there is never a point within the range where `p = E`.  Actually, I'm not sure what variable we're integrating over.